# Mgo omit field even when not empty

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I was wondering if there is any way to have a stuct field that doesn't get commited to mgo even if it isn't empty.

The only way I have found to do this is to make the field lowercase, which makes it a pain to access. Is there another way?

This is an example, and my goal here is to not commit the SSN into the database but still have it uppercase.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
    "crypto/sha1"
    "encoding/base64"
    "labix.org/v2/mgo"
)

type Person struct{
  Name string
  SSN string
  HashedSSN string
}

func main() {
  bob := Person{"Bob", "fake_ssn", ""}
  hasher := sha1.New()
  hasher.Write( []byte(bob.SSN))
  sha := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil))
  bob.HashedSSN = sha
  mgoSession, err := mgo.Dial("localhost:27017")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("mongo_config#initMongoSessions : Could not dial to mgoSession", err)
  } else {
    mgoSession.DB("test").C("person").Insert(bob)
  }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can do that by using the field tag as follows:

```
type T struct {
    Field string `bson:"-"`
}
```

Comment: Sweet, you are very helpful Gustavo